# why shape is change when we add or remove vertex in timeline after effect

Tags: keyframe, after-effects

I want draw shape that is change in timeline with make some keyframe with "path" 
for Ex: the first keyframe include 3 vertex and next keyframe have 4 vertex. 
when i add extra keyframe in time line for new keyframe the shape in last keyframe will change! why? or when i delete vertex the shape in last keyframe will change

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add or remove vertex from a shape in the timeline.   You can only animate them.
Pick a place you can hide the vertex and key frame it from there.

For example.  If you wanted a triangle to become a square. you'd make a triangle but with 4 vertex points.   You could hide the 4th vertex inline on one side, and then keyframe the top points to make a square.   After effects doesn't "generate" new shapes in the way you're thinking.

See the 4 points?

[Triangle with 4 vertex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbFsi.png)

This should then be animated in your timeline to your desired position and thus, the shape you want.

[Keyframed Square from Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c22y.png)